# collection.watch() is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset, changestream

I wanna use MongoDB as a real-time database using changestreams in my node js app but I get the error

> TypeError: collection.watch is not a function

The version of my MongoDB is 4.0.9. Am I doing something wrong while setting up replicaset?

My connection to database has a uri like this

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://...?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs");
```

and I run mongo with this command

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --replSet rs
```

Comment: show the code where you got this error

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of your current code which sets up the change stream and mention of the specific version of the Node.js driver you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Update your mongodb node package to 3.0

```
npm install mongodb@3.0 --save
```

then connect to mongodb in your terminal and run

```
rs.initiate()
```

change your code for mongodb in your nodejs script to the new 3.0 standard and then the watcher should work.